# Android Programming.Why is my line of coding unreachable

Tags: java

I've been coding for a bit trying to link two `activties` and I'm nearly there but I've run into a problem.

A line of my coding is unreachable. Can anyone explain why?

```
package com.example.twolink

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}  

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class));
            finish();
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your Button on the onCreate method like so :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class));
        finish();
    }  
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

If you want to hide the button initially, use the `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to toggle the button visibility. Then, if you want to show it later, you can `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` elsewhere.

Comment: so all i do is add that coding instead of the other coding and the buuton should launch activity2

Comment: if you click button2, then yes, it should launch MainActivity2 (assuming you defined MainActivity2 in your AndroidMainfest.xml). if you want to programmatically want to auto click your button, you can also directly call button2.performClick() in your oncreate method, which will launch MainActivity2 without even clicking button2.

Comment: so in the layout that contains the button do i have to add anything to the button

Comment: yeah did you define your button in activity_main.xml? if so, it should show up automatically.

Comment: what do u mean define.i added the button if thats what your asking but i meant do i need to add somthing to thge button in the main.xml

Comment: your question is not clear. if you added your button correctly to activity_main.xml, it should show up correctly. beyond that, i don't understand what you mean by "add something". that is not the correct programming terminology so i'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: ok i figured that out and do i put the coding above in the place where i was trying to iniatailize my button

Answer (score 2):

In `onOptionsItemSelected(...)`, you `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` right after the `switch` block. At this point your method exits. Everything after that is unreachable code.

Comment: so if i remove the onOptionsItemSelected code the rest should becpme reachable

Comment: Well, yes, *but* then you're not returning anything from your function unless your `switch` case evaluates. You need to think about what you want your function to do, and read about how `return` works.

Comment: well im just trying to link two activiteis and i cant find out how anywhere on the net so could u point me to some good tuts please if u know of any and thanks for the help